# Como sincronizar las compras de Amazon en Odoo?

Tags: odoo

estoy tratando de sincronizar ordenes de Amazon en Odoo pues ya vinculé la licencia y todo, pero al momento de sincronizar las ordenes me aparece este mensaje:

"Se encontró un error al sincronizar los pedidos de Amazon. ForbiddenRequestBlocked: Developer is blocked from making calls for the MWS section Orders as part of MWS Deprecation process"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Parece que la app esta desactualizada. Que versión de odoo estas utilizando?

Comment: La versión es odoo 15